# How to get Top 5 Elements From Array in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

what i need:

- i want top 5 element from the array .

here is the array:

```
 data: [
 {
 company_id: "42172",
 Product_Name: "Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 05),In-Line Amplification 
 Systems,Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 03),Band Combiner Devicestcs infosys 
  polaris accenture fggghh ffghggghmnhg fghfggh fg fgfg f ffg fgfg bfggf fghg gghg  
 fgbfgg,Ethernet Access System,The Introductory Transport System,Intelligent Ethernet 
  Access System (Ieas 06),Top End Transport System,Intelligent Ethernet Access   
  System,Ethernet Aggregation Device,Our Mid Level Transport System",
  Company_Website: "http://www.xkl.com/",
 company_name: "XKL",
 city_name: "Kirkland",
 country_names: "USA",
 comp_img: "http://10times.com/pics/company/3671/logo.jpg"
  },
```

*  how to fetch the top 5 product name from array.

here is my  code

```
                   {% if(item.Product_Name)|length < 300 %}
                    {% set foo = item.Product_Name|split(',') %}
                    {% for i in  foo|slice(0, 4) %}
                     {{ i }}
                              {% if(loop.last)< 5 %}
                            ,
                            {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            {% set foo = item.Product_Name|split(',') %}
                    {% for i in  foo|slice(0, 5) %}
                     {{ i }}
                              {% if(loop.last)< 5 %}
                            ,
                            {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

- i just want to fetch the top five element from product name .
- consider product name :-

  ```
   line 1: a, 
   line 2 :b,
   line 3 :c,
   line 4:d, 
   line 5 :e
  ```

  consider if length of character of top five elements are greater then says 300 , then i
  t restrict the condition and line 5  does not occur.

Comment: I didn't really get your question but you have a bit too much logic in your template. I would consider do those operations in the controller.

Comment: @Hpatoio is right about tons of logic in template. But try like this: in your model make public method `getShortName()`. Split string there and return first 5 elements. Than in twig template use `item.shortName` instead